# failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, codec

Whenever I run a .py file from the terminal or in another way I get this error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Python311\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32',
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Lib',
    'C:\\Python311',
  ]
```

Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

What's the problem? I'm a total beginner in this kind of stuff so it could be dumb

I wanted the script to run regularly, but when I open it it opens and closes and from the terminal I get this error. This happens on all Python scripts I use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.